# Which php.ini file do I edit?

Tags: php, windows, mysqli

Mysqli isn't working on php 7.4.9, and all the suggestions I find tell me to edit php.ini. Unfortunately, I seem to have 2 of them in C:\php. php.ini.development, and php.ini.production. Which one should I be editing?

Comment: Use `phpinfo()` to see which ini files are used.